# angular.copy throws Illegal invocation error when performed on DOM object

Tags: angularjs, dom

I need to create a copy of an DOM object so that modifying the copy does not modify the original DOM. Tried achieving the same using the following code

```
var image = angular.element('#image').find('svg')[0];
var imageToDownload = angular.copy(image);
```

But this throws Illegal invocation error. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: This *feels like* an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).    What is it **you are actually trying to solve**?  Modifying the DOM is something that is discouraged in Angular, and creating a copy of a DOM object to keep the original DOM from being being modified really feels like you are tying to solve your unknown problem in a non angular sort of way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no way to copy dom objects like images via `angular.copy` (see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14352) issue on github)

Try to use the native method `Node.cloneNode()` instead, this way:

```
var image = angular.element('#image').find('svg')[0];
var imageToDownload = image.cloneNode();
```

You can find some ducumentation about `cloneNode` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).